# mod_auth_radius secure over https?

Tags: apache-2.2, radius, freeradius, mod-auth

mod_auth_radius README file says:

```
Using static passwords & RADIUS authentication over the web is a BAD
IDEA.  Everyone can sniff the passwords, as they're sent over the net
in the clear.
```

If I serve the page over https, will it be secure then? Or is that not what is meant by the statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, over https basic auth is secure. Additionally between the RADIUS server and the HTTP server the passwords are reversibly encrypted using the RADIUS shared secret.